# Authenticate user in firebase project with existing Shopify user/account

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, shopify

I'm building an app for an existing Shopify shop. Users that have an account for this Shopify shop should be able to log in with their existing account in the new app. In other words, they should not be required to have to create a new account in my app but be able to login with the email and password of their existing Shopify account.

This app uses Firebase as a BaaS and the Shopify shop is on Shopify Plus.

Is this behavior possible and if yes, how to I set this up?

Comment: Firebase consists of 18+ products, so can you specify which specific product(s) you use? Also: how are the Firebase products you use supposed to use the information about the (Shopify) user?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm talking about Firebase Authentication. Specifically, I'm trying to find out if it is possible to use a Shopify Shop as a sign-in method, so a user who has a Shopify account can sign into my app with the email and password of this Shopify account.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sign your Shopify users in with Firebase, you'll need to [mint a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) for them (in a trusted environment) and then use that token (on the client) to [sign in to Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients).

Comment: At this point it likely becomes of a Shopify question but do you have an idea how to achieve this with Shopify? I could set up a cloud function for my Firebase project as my trusted environment, but how do I authenticate my users against Shopify? Would my users send their Shopify email and password to my cloud function and I use their credentials to sign in to Shopify, if that is even possible? I feel like this is not the right approach as I don't want to get the user's Shopify credentials, if that makes sense...